# CSS Hover / Border Issue

Tags: html, jquery, css, sass, css-selectors

This is the issue I'm having - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/512540?key=604f2d2682f6ef8061da033e213eaa58

I want the `hover` border to disappear whenever one of the options is selected so there isn't the dual borders look. I've tried a mixture of css and jquery so far, but I still can't seem to get the desired style.

This is my DOM:

```
<div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="0">
 <div class="header">Size</div>

  <div data-value="Small" class="swatch-element small available">
    
    <input id="swatch-0-small" type="radio" name="option-0" value="Small" checked="">
    
    <label for="swatch-0-small">
      Small
      <img class="crossed-out" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0317/8410/8172/t/6/assets/soldout.png?779">
    </label>
    
  </div>

<script>
  jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="0"] .small').removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
</script>




  <div data-value="Medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    
    <input id="swatch-0-medium" type="radio" name="option-0" value="Medium">
    
    <label for="swatch-0-medium">
      Medium
      <img class="crossed-out" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0317/8410/8172/t/6/assets/soldout.png?779">
    </label>
    
  </div>

<script>
  jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="0"] .medium').removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
</script>



  <div data-value="Large" class="swatch-element large available">
    
    <input id="swatch-0-large" type="radio" name="option-0" value="Large">
    
    <label for="swatch-0-large">
      Large
      <img class="crossed-out" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0317/8410/8172/t/6/assets/soldout.png?779">
    </label>
    
  </div>

<script>
  jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="0"] .large').removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
</script>
```

This is the CSS I'm currently using:

```
.swatch-element {
  border: solid 2px #a1a1a1;
}

.swatch-element:hover {
  border-color: #000;
}

.swatch input:checked + label {
  border: solid #000 2px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried box-sizing: border-box?

Answer (score 1):

You could apply *all* borders to the `label`, so there would be no double borders, but just a change of border:

```
.swatch-element label {
  border: solid 2px #a1a1a1;
}

.swatch-element:hover label {
  border-color: #000;
}

.swatch-element input:checked + label {
  border: solid #000 2px;
}
```